# Unable to create Mapping Entity with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

A. I have a entity EntityA like below:

```
Table - EntityA(id long PK, name varchar)

@Entity @Table
EntityA{
    @Id
    long id;

    String name;
}
```

B. Based on this I want to fetch data in below class through JPA(using unidirectional mapping):

```
@Entity @Table
EntityMap{

    long id;

    @OneToOne
    EntityA entity;

    @OneToMany
    List<EntityA> mappedEntity;
}
```

C. To make it work for now I have created an entity like below:

```
Table - entity_map(id long pk, source_entity_id long FK-EntityA_id, target_entity_id long FK-EntityA_id)

@Entity @Table
EntityMap{

    @Id
    long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_entity_id")
    EntityA sourceEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_entity_id")
    EntityA targetEntity;
}
```

This is working as expected but I need entity explained in #B. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

A `@OneToMany` relationship can be archieved by

```
@JoinColumn(name = "entity_map_id")
@OneToMany
List<EntityA> mappedEntity;
```

In your `EntityA` table you need a column `entity_map_id` and a `foreign key (entity_map_id) references EntityMap(id)` constraint.

If you cannot change the `EntityA` table you need a `@JoinTable` to perform the mapping:

```
@JoinTable(name = "JOIN_TABLE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MY_ENTITY_MAP_FK")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_A_FK")})
@OneToMany
List<EntityA> mappedEntity;
```

The join table contains two columns `ENTITY_A_FK` and `MY_ENTITY_MAP_FK`:

```
create table JOIN_TABLE(
  ENTITY_A_FK integer not null,
  MY_ENTITY_MAP_FK integer not null
);
```

Comment: Yes...But I am expecting unidirectional mapping. that's why I skipped this mapping. I am not allowed to change EntityA .

Comment: Ok, then you need a join table to do the mapping.

Comment: So, Do I need to create separate table JOIN_TABLE? Can you please update code snip with actual table and column names?

Comment: Yes, in this case you need a separate table to store the mapping. I added short desc. of the table.